# How to create function which return array of widgets

Tags: flutter

I have to create a function which returns array of widgets, like this:

```
new GridView.count(crossAxisCount: _column,children: getRandomWidgetArray(),
```

Example function like this:-

```
Widget[] getRandomWidgetArray()
    {
      Widget[] gameCells;
      for(i=0;i<5;i++)
       {
          gameCells.add(new MyCellWidget(i));
       }
      return gameCells;
    }
```

Above code is giving this error:

[image]

I know how to do it without function:

```
children: < Widget >[ new MyCellWidget(0),
                      new MyCellWidget(1),]
```

But I have to make it dynamic with function as values will change in future, above code is just prototype. Flutter examples are very few.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Array types are `List<Type>` in Dart:

```
List<Widget> getRandomWidgetArray()
```

`[]` can only be used as literal value to create a new list value, not for type declaration.

Answer (score 6):

At this time, the following code is deprecated:

```
List <Widget> gameCells = List<Widget>();
```

Use the following instead:

```
List <Widget> gameCells = <Widget>[];
```

The first code will work anyway, but you will have a warning.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Widget> getRandomWidgetArray(){

  List <Widget> gameCells = List<Widget>();
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
   {
      gameCells.add(new MyCellWidget(i));
   }
  return gameCells;
}
```

This is the correct way of initializing List, adding elements and returning Widget list.