# How to return <Widget>[ ] in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been try like this but it does not work

// Tabs class

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return <Widget>[
        // list of widget
     ]
  }
```

I want to implement like this

// Other Page

```
new TabBar(
   tabs: Tabs()
)
```

Comment: Your explanation is a little bit vague one what you want to achieve. But if you want to use tabs, check the documentation at https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs

Comment: I think you can create custom function "Tabs" and return widgets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create function which return array of widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50348071/how-to-create-function-which-return-array-of-widgets)

Answer (score 2):

1. Add tabs.dart page
2. put following code in the page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    List<Tab> Tabs() {
      List<Tab> tabs = [
        Tab(),
        Tab(),
        Tab(),
        Tab(),
        Tab(),
        Tab(),
        Tab(),
      ];
      return tabs;
    }
```

3. import 'tabs.dart';

```
import 'tabs.dart';

new TabBar(
   tabs: Tabs()
)
```